# Ajax - url not working - Pl help me

Tags: php

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost/php/chk.php',
   data: formdata,
   dateType: 'json',
   success: function(resp) {
       if ( resp == true ) { alert ('ok'); } else { alert ('not ok'); }
   }
});


 <form id="contact" action="#" method="post">
   <input name="name" type="text"/>
   <input name="email_address" type="text"/>
   <textarea name="message"/></textarea>
   <button id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what is `formdata`?

Comment: what do you mean by `url not working`

Comment: Please go learn how to ask a question. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If `formdata` is supposed to be an instance of a `FormData` object then perhaps
you could do this

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost/php/chk.php',
   data: ( new FormData( document.getElementById('contact') ) ),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function( resp ) {
       if ( resp == true ) { alert ('ok'); } else { alert ('not ok'); }
   }
});
```

Comment: $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: 'http://localhost/php/chk.php',
                       data: (new FormData('#contact')[0]),
                       dataType: 'json',
                       success: function(resp) {
                           if ( resp == true ) { alert ('ok'); } else { alert ('not ok'); }
                       }
                      });